# How to combine two linear color of a background?

Tags: css

There is a liner color of two background.
[image]

There is a line in the two background.
Can it be mixed? I mean it from left to right and from up to down.

```
.a{
background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5ae2c7 0%, #2fd1d1 100%);
}

.b{
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2fd1d1 0%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

How to combine the two `background` to one?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two colors into a gradient fairly easily by using linear-gradient().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score -1):

You can use like : The top layer can be coded like this: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(124,212,207, 1), rgba(124,212,207,0)). Note that the corresponding rgb colors of #7cd4cf is rgb(124,212,207).

```
.foo {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(124, 212, 207, 1), rgba(124, 212, 207, 0)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #7cd4cf, #7cd4cf 1.5px, #49c8c1 2px, #49c8c1 4px);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

<div class="foo">

</div>
```

you can design as per your requirement..

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but have you tried? I do not want to combine like what you give me. but want to fix the line between the two background.

Comment: you need to use single class or single div not use (.a and .b)

Comment: I am sharing my testing code with your color combination

    .foo {
      background-image:
        linear-gradient(180deg, #59e0c8, #43d5d3),
        repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #59e0c8, #59e0c8, #43d5d3, #43d5d3);
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    
    <div class="foo">
    </div>